# How to proof that $\phi^6$ theory is non-renormalizable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, renormalization

I'm studying QFT at beginner level. In the lecture, we never showed in detail that the $\phi^4$ theory is renormalizable and we are asked to show that $\phi^6$ theory is non-renormalizable.

I guess this should be easier as to show something is renormalizable, but I need some input how I can proof this rigorously?

Comment: What textbook are you using? If Peskin & Shchroeder, have you looked at page 315 and following? If not, look for "superficial degree of divergence" in your textbook's index.

Comment: Closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/208553/50583

Answer (score 3):

Let's call:

V = number of vertices

I = number of internal lines, E = number of external lines.

For the general connected Feynman diagrams of $\phi^6$-theory, each vertex has 6 half-lines, each internal line connects 2 half-lines, so the number of external lines is:
$$E = 6V-2I$$
The number of loops is:
$$L = 2V+1-\frac{E}{2}$$
(you can convince yourself)

The superficial degree of divergence is defined by:
$$D = \textrm{number of factors of internal momentum in the numerator} −
\textrm{number of factors of internal momentum in the denominator}$$
For the scalar theory, $D = 4L - 2I$ (convince yourself!). So, the superficial degree of divergence for $\phi^6$-theory:
$$D = 2V-E+4$$
Let's look back at the superficial degree of divergence for $\phi^4$-theory:
$$D = 4-E$$.

1. D of $\phi^4$-theory does not depend on the number of vertices, or the order of pertubation theory. For a diagrams to be divergent, $D\ge 0$, the number of external lines is finite. This means there is a limit number of divergent diagrams => renormalizable.
2. However that is not the case for the $\phi^6$-theory whose D depends on the number of vertices. So $\phi^6$-theory is non-renormalizable.

Comment: Careful in the phrasing at the end: The number of divergent *diagrams* of $\phi^4$-theory is actually infinite (there are diverging diagrams at each order of the perturbation series), but the number of divergent total *amplitudes* is finite (only those with $E=0,2,4$). A theory with a finite number of diverngent diagrams would be called "super-renormalizable" by some. Additionally, I think it would improve your answer if you were more explicit about why the degree of divergence actually measures divergence, and what "numerator" and "denominator" you are talking about.

Comment: @ACuriousMind The numerator and denominator here are of the Feynman integrals (including $d^4q$). The degree of divergence is corresponding to the mass dimension of the diagrams (and, of course, of the Feynman integrals): $1/q^{D}$. So it reflects the divergent property.

Also, thank you for correcting my mistake.

Comment: I know what you're talking about :) I was just suggesting to edit that into your answer since it might be valuable for learners.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume we have a field theory with $V(\phi)~=~a\phi^6$ The Lagrangian density is then 
$$
{\cal L}~=~\frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi~-~ a\phi^6.
$$
The action $S~=~\int d^4x{\cal L}$ is dimensionless in natural units. This means in units $[\phi]~=~1/\ell$. Given this potential we then must have $[a]~=~\ell^2$

We have for a standard harmonic oscillator free field $V(\phi)~=~\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2$ the straightforwards evaluation of the two point function 
$$
\langle|\phi(x)\phi(y)|\rangle~=~\frac{1}{4\pi}\frac{1}{|x~-~y|^2},
$$
where we think of $|x~-~y|~=~\delta$ as the cut off in the scalar potential $V(|\phi|)$. This then gives the renormalization correction to the mass
$$
\frac{m^2}{2}~=~\frac{m_b^2}{2}~+~k\frac{m_b^2 }{\delta^2},
$$
for $k$ a constant and $m_b$ the bare mass. This type of analysis can be done for any orders on $\phi$

Now let us look at $\phi^6$. The most elementary diagram involves $6$ lines at a vertex. For each line a $\Delta$ evaluated from $\delta$ to $\infty$ the amplitude will scale as
$$
a\int_\delta^\infty\frac{d^4\Delta}{\Delta^6}~=~\frac{a}{\delta^2}.
$$
This is rather inconvenient, for we do not normally work with 6 lines at a vertex. Instead real processes are going to be graphs similar to these below:
[image]

This means that we have an integration of the form
$$
a\int_\delta^\infty d^4\Delta\int_\delta^\infty d^4\Delta\frac{1}{\Delta^6}~=~\delta^2~-~\lim_{\Delta\rightarrow\infty}\Delta^2.
$$
That is really bad. This is terribly divergent for large distances. For this reason you never see field operators in standard QFT with powers larger than $4$.

Comment: Ty for your answer now things are clearer. But the only thing I don't get is why we can conclude there doesn't exist any ''counter terms" like in $\phi^4$ theory they "compensate the divergence"?

Comment: Counter terms are usually computed for some cut-off, here I write as $\delta$.  It is not clear in this case how so set a cut off at this large scale.

Comment: Several things in this answer are unclear to me: 1. From what "straightforward evaluation" does your two-point function result? The standard result for the not-time-ordered two-point function in d dimensions is $\langle \phi(x)\phi(y)\rangle = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{p^2 + m^2}}\mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i}p(x-y)}\frac{\mathrm{d}^d p}{(2\pi)^d}$, and it is not at all evident to me how that becomes $\frac{1}{\lvert x -y\rvert^2}$. 2. How did you arrive at the "renormalization correction" to the mass just from that? You didn't specify any renormalization scheme.

Comment: 3. What do you mean by *"for we do not normally work with 6 lines at a vertex"* - if you have a $\phi^6$-theory, that's *precisely* what you are supposed to do! What's a "real process" and why should it look more like the diagrams you draw thereafter? 4. What does intergrating $1/\Delta^6$ *twice* with respect to delta *mean*, and how did you get the $\delta^2$ after that? How is this a proof of non-renormalizability? A theory with a finite number of diverging amplitudes is *still* (power-counting) renormalizable, no matter how badly divergent individual diagrams may be.

Comment: For #1 The propagator is a standard result. That is something from memory. For #2 processes really should have three legs connected to a vertex. For the Higgs field this is a bit of an exception, but I will not belabor that. So for something like $\phi^6$ most real processes will have off-shell stuff. In the heuristic I present, and this is meant to be physical motivating, a vertex with 6 lines would be $\sim~1/\delta^2$. Other processes though will not be renormalizable, and integrating twice reflects the fact you have different points the fields are evaluated on.

Comment: For #1, I would appreciate a reference, since I can only find my Fourier transformed version in the  standard refernceses. By #2, I suppose you actually addressed my *third point*, and I don't see at all why processes should have only three legs attached to a vertex - non-Abelian gauge theories contain genuine four-point vertices, for example. You did not addressmy second and forth points at all.